# Azure Machine Learning Studio designer - "create new version" unexpected when registering a data set

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to register a data set as a Python step with the Azure Machine Learning Studio designer. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from azureml.core import Workspace, Run, Dataset

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    run = Run.get_context()
    ws = run. experiment.workspace
    ds = Dataset.from_pandas_dataframe(dataframe1)
    ds.register(workspace = ws,
                name = "data set name",
                description = "example description",
                create_new_version = True)
    return dataframe1,
```

I get an error saying that "create_new_version" in the ds.register line was an unexpected keyword argument. However, this keyword appears in the documentation and I need it to keep track of new versions of the file.

If I remove the argument, I get a different error: "Local data source path not supported for this operation", so it still does not work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: well written question -- thanks! can you explain more about why you need to register a dataset *inside* of a Python step?

Comment: Is it so you can use that dataset in another pipeline? If it's within the pipeline, have you seen the "Convert to Dataset" module?

Comment: Thanks for replying! That´s correct. I do some data manipulation and then register the dataset, which will be used as input data for a model from outside the pipeline. A new version of the same dataset needs to be generated anytime the data changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### update

sharing OP's solution here for easier discovery

```py
import pandas as pd
from azureml.core import Workspace, Run, Dataset

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    run = Run.get_context()
    ws = run. experiment.workspace
    datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()
    ds = Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe(
        dataframe1, datastore, 'data_set_name',
        description = 'data set description.')
    return dataframe1,
```

### original answer

Sorry you're struggling. You're very close!

A few things may be the culprit here.

1. It looks like you're using the `Dataset` class, which has been deprecated. I recommend trying `Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe()` ([docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.dataset_factory.tabulardatasetfactory?view=azure-ml-py#register-pandas-dataframe-dataframe--target--name--description-none--tags-none--show-progress-true-)) instead of `Dataset.from_pandas_dataframe()`. ([more about the Dataset API deprecation](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/work-with-data/dataset-api-change-notice.md))
2. More conjectire here, but another thing is there might be some limitations to using dataset registration within an "Execute Python Script" (EPS) module due to:

   1. the workspace object might not have the right permissions
   2. you might not be able to use the `register_pandas_dataframe` method inside the EPS module, but might have better luck with save the dataframe first to parquet, then calling `Dataset.Tabular.from_parquet_files`

Hopefully something works here!

Comment: Thanks! so that other people can try my solution, this is what worked: removed the ds = Dataset.from_pandas_dataframe and ds.register lines, and added the following: datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()   and ds = Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe(dataframe1, datastore, 'data_set_name', description = 'data set description.')  .  Thanks again!